# How to get the rating tag of a .m4a file in C#

Tags: c#, tags, taglib, m4a, taglib-sharp

I work with TagLib# to get the ratings of my .mp3 files this part is working so far, but I have absolutely no idea how to get the rating of a m4a file.

This is how i get the rating of a .mp3 file, but it doesn't work for m4a:

```
TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create(Dateipfad);
Tag tag = file.GetTag(TagLib.TagTypes.Id3v2);
TagLib.Id3v2.PopularimeterFrame rating = TagLib.Id3v2.PopularimeterFrame.Get((TagLib.Id3v2.Tag)tag, "Windows Media Player 9 Series", true);
byte rate = rating.Rating;
```

How can I get the rating of an m4a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but mp3tag, winamp, and twonky use the %rate% atom.

windows explorer writes to its own proprietary atom, but idk which one.  (trying to figure that out is how I found this page)

iTunes afaik only keeps ratings in its DB and doesn't write them to tags.

mp3 uses id3, while m4a uses atoms.

Answer (score 0):

use https://atldotnet.codeplex.com/ for reading tag from a lot of format (mp3,m4a...)

and TagLib# for read/write (instal it from NuGet)

Comment: ATL .NET supports tag reading **and** writing since september 2017 - the project has moved to https://github.com/Zeugma440/atldotnet and has a NuGet packaging too